# How to convert a time format in hhmmss.mm to normal time in R?

Tags: r, date, time, format

I have a time format written in hhmmss.mm, such 225014.09 imported from a table.
It's earthquake time. I wanna transform it into 22:50:14(:09?) in R.

I don't know what to do with the milliseconds. It should be the above way. Can anyone help me out? I've searched and searched, but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: `as.POSIXct('225014.09', tz = 'UTC', format = '%H%M%OS')`, though that will insert today's date.

Comment: If you don't care/want a datetime object, you can create the string by splitting it and inserting the colons: `t <- 225014.09; paste0(substr(t,1,2),":",substr(t,3,4),":",substr(t,5,6))`

Comment: Regex version of the string: `gsub('(..)(..)(..)\\.(.+)', '\\1:\\2:\\3(:\\4)','225014.09')`

Comment: thank you guys all for the valuable input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two general rules for this:

1. Don't use regular expressions for parsing dates and times
2. Follow rule 1.

In all seriousness, *use a datetime parser* of which R has *many*. But a key here is that you have a *time* and not yet a *date* so you cannot yet parse as a *datetime*.

So do something like this:

```
R> tstr <- "225014.09"
R> dtstr <- paste("2026-01-01", tstr)  # which date does not matter
R> pt <- anytime(dtstr)                # now it is parsed
R> pt
[1] "2026-01-01 22:50:14.08 CST"
R> tstr <- "225014.09"
R> dtstr <- paste("2016-01-01", tstr)  # which date does not matter
R> pt <- anytime(dtstr)                # now it is parsed
R> pt
[1] "2016-01-01 22:50:14.08 CST"
R> hhmmss <- format(pt, "%H:%M:%OS")
R> hhmmss
[1] "22:50:14.089999"
R>
```

Now we have the preferred hh:mm:ss.ff with fractional seconds -- my default is but you can fine-tune:

```
R> options(digits.secs=2)
R> hhmmss <- format(pt, "%H:%M:%OS")
R> hhmmss
[1] "22:50:14.08"
R>
```

The fact that '09' got rounded to '08' is one of those things with floating point math, and cannot be changed by how you parse or format -- it is a limitation of the underlying representation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and the example!

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow.  You can now 'accept' this answer (click on the tickmark), and/or 'upvote' (click on the triangle facing up).